# Why I need an extra space in the regex pattern to make it work properly?

Tags: python, regex

When I write following code:

```
m = re.findall('\sf.*?\s','a f fast and friendly dog');
```

I get **output**: `[' f ', ' friendly ']`

But when I provide extra space between f & fast, I get following output which I expected from the previous one.
Code is as follows

```
m = re.findall('\sf.*?\s','a f  fast and friendly dog');
```

**Output:**

```
[' f ', ' fast ', ' friendly ']
```

Can anyone tell me why I am not getting later output in first case (without inserting extra space between f & fast)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because your pattern ends in `\s`. ***Regex matches are non-overlapping***, so the first match `' f '` matches the trailing space, making the rest of the string begin with `'fast'` instead of `' fast'`. `'fast'` does not match a pattern starting with `\s`

Comment: What should be the regex then?
Should it include parenthesis extraction?

Comment: If the trailing space should exist, but not be consumed, you should use a [lookahead](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html?highlight=lookahead). `/\sf.*?(?=\s)/`

Comment: I'm guessing what you're after is `\bf.*?\b` - [illustrated here](https://regex101.com/r/Hh24xG/1).

Comment: Would `f\w*` or `f[a-z]*` be more simpler?

Comment: @kitman0804 `f\w*` would not match `' f123456 '` which OP's code will match. Certainly simpler, but also possibly less correct! :)

Answer (score 1):

The space is consumed by `' f '` after it is matched. Now the next search starts from `'fast and friendly dog'`. But now `fast` does not have a leading space and thus does not match.

If you want the space not be consumed then try a positive lookbehind search.